# Checking for existing record in the SQL database

Tags: java, sql, record, exists

i have made a car rental management system in JAVA and SQL. The data base is working fine with no problems. i am stuck at checking if the data already exists in the database? like if a person enters NIC of 355353553.. it shouldn't be entered again.. Any suggestions about what i should do? thanks for any help!

Comment: You can set NIC to a unique key in your dbms.

Comment: yes it is that.. but i need it to show an error message.. can you help with that?

Comment: Try to select a person if there is nothing, return error, otherwise do something

Comment: You can try just running the INSERT statement and catch an exception to check (assuming that the SQL is correct)

Comment: yes i can try that! thanks for the suggestion. i'll let you know if that works!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Check out primary keys or unique constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can set unique columns in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars
(
car_id int NOT NULL,
NIC int NOT NULL,
...
...
....
UNIQUE (car_id, NIC)
```

)

for more info, have a look here: [Unique - sql  syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Since you already have the database set to be unique, it sounds like you just want a method for handling errors in this case. I would use something like this personally, however I would bet that there is a more effective solution.

Create a method to get the count of the results from a query. In my example, I just called it countMethod. Have it return the number of rows from the query. You could alternatively use COUNT(*) from MySQL if you want to avoid using the java code. Here is some sudo code to get you started if you decided to try to implement.

```
int total = countMethod("SELECT id FROM the_table WHERE id=" + inputID);
if(total > 0) {
    //Throw a warning message, it already exists
} else {
    //Insert it into the database
}
```